# How to output an array starting from the value with the highest character match count in php

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have been trying to match a string with the values in an array and output the array strings starting from the string with the highest character match count. for example:

```
$array = array(
'mike'=>'book21',
'ben'=>'buzz',
'jack'=>'airdrone',
'july'=>'march',
'fred'=>'blend45'
 );
$string = 'blenmaio2';
```

As you can see, **'blend45'**, has the highest matched characters, with a total of 4 matched characters. I want to be able to output them starting from the first four highest match count, here is an example of the output i want:

> 1. blend45
> 2. book21
> 3. march
> 4. buzz

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem, calculating the matches, sorting...?

Comment: why `march` is number 3 and `buzz` in 4 ?

Comment: i tried similar_text() but couldn't get it to work with max() function.

Answer (score 3):

I think the `levenshtein()` function would be the most appropriate method to achieve your goal:

```
$array = array(
    'mike'=>'book21',
    'ben'=>'buzz',
    'jack'=>'airdrone',
    'july'=>'march',
    'fred'=>'blend45'
);

$string = 'blenmaio2';

uasort($array, function($a, $b) use ($string) {
    $aDistance = levenshtein($string, $a);
    $bDistance = levenshtein($string, $b);

    return ($aDistance < $bDistance) ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($array);

// Output:
// Array
// (
//     [fred] => blend45
//     [july] => march
//     [mike] => book21
//     [ben] => buzz
//     [jack] => airdrone
// )
```

http://php.net/levenshtein

**Update** Use `uasort()` instead of `usort()` to preserve the array keys.

*I just noticed that my answer compares the similarity, but doesn't meet the highest character count match, so sorry for that :)*

Comment: Using `levenshtein` for this is clever!

Comment: I just updated my answer with the correct implementation, because I first didn't use `$string` (facepalm).

Answer (score 3):

This is my first time trying to help someone, so hopefully this does the trick. I know you can probably simplify the code a little, but this is what I have.

```
<?php
$array = array(
'mike'=>'book21',
'ben'=>'buzz',
'jack'=>'airdrone',
'july'=>'march',
'fred'=>'blend45'
 );
$string = 'blenmaio2';
$sort_array=array(); //Empty array


foreach ($array as $key => $value){
$num = similar_text($value,$string); //Using similar text to compar the strings.
$sort_array[$value] = $num; //Adding the compared number value and sring value to array.
}
arsort($sort_array, SORT_REGULAR);//Sorting the array by the larges number.

print_r ($sort_array);

//creating another foreach statement to get the output you wanted.
$count = 0;
foreach($sort_array as $key => $value){
$count++;
echo $count.". ".$key."\n";
};
?>
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [blend45] => 4
    [book21] => 3
    [airdrone] => 3
    [march] => 2
    [buzz] => 1
)
1. blend45
2. book21
3. airdrone
4. march
5. buzz
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are my answer. It is a bit different, because I'm using levenshtein function for finding nearest between two words.
I'm using uasort to reorder the array in way you liked.
Of course you can replace the algorithm for nearest by your function.

```
<?php
$array = array(
'mike'=>'book21',
'ben'=>'buzz',
'jack'=>'airdrone',
'july'=>'march',
'fred'=>'blend45'
 );
$string = 'blenmaio2';

function cmp($a,$b){
    global $string;
    $aa=levenshtein($a, $string);
    $bb=levenshtein($b, $string);
    if($aa>$bb)
        return 1;
    elseif($bb>$aa)
        return -1;
    else return 0;
}

uasort($array,cmp);

?>

<pre><?= print_r($array); ?></pre>
```